EEG PSD Difference in MNE Python and MATLAB graphs
I'm trying to replicate something in python that a peer did in MATLAB which is plot the PSD for a mouse eeg. However, when logging and then plotting the data the exact same way in using the welch function in python, the shape of the graph is identical but y-axis values are completely different.
Here is the MATLAB code and an example of one of the graphs generated.

eeglab nogui;


data_dir = '/Users/andrewxue/Documents/MATLAB/mousedata';
save_dir = '/Users/andrewxue/Documents/MATLAB/data/matlabgraphs';
frequencies = [4, 35, 40, 45];
species = {'mouse1', 'mouse2'};
days = {'Day1', 'Day2'};
baseline_str = 'baseline';


for iSpecies = 1:length(species)
    for iFreq = 1:length(frequencies)
        psd_data = [];
        psd_data_pre = [];
        labels = {};
        
        for iDay = 1:length(days)
            day_dir = fullfile(data_dir, days{iDay});
            files = dir(fullfile(day_dir, '*.edf'));
            
            for iFile = 1:length(files)
                filename = files(iFile).name;
                
                
                if contains(filename, species{iSpecies}) && ...
                   (contains(filename, [num2str(frequencies(iFreq)) 'hz']) || contains(filename, baseline_str))
                   
                   
                   EEG = pop_biosig(fullfile(day_dir, filename));
                   EEG = eeg_checkset(EEG);
                   
                   
                   data1 = EEG.data(1, :);
                   data2 = EEG.data(2, :);

                   
                   window = hamming(1024);
                   noverlap = 512;
                   nfft = 1024;
                   [psd1, freq] = pwelch(data1, window, noverlap, nfft, EEG.srate);
                   total_power1 = trapz(freq, psd1);
                   [psd2, freq] = pwelch(data2, window, noverlap, nfft, EEG.srate);
                   total_power2 = trapz(freq, psd2);
    
                   if total_power1 < total_power2
                       psd = psd1;
                   elseif total_power2 < total_power1
                       psd = psd2;
                   end

                   
                   psd_data = [psd_data; psd'];
                   if contains(filename, baseline_str)
                       labels{end+1} = [days{iDay} ' baseline'];
                   else
                       labels{end+1} = [days{iDay} ' ' num2str(frequencies(iFreq)) 'hz'];
                   end
                end
            end
        end
        
        
        %psd_data_pre = psd_data;
        %psd_data = [psd_data_pre(1,:)-psd_data_pre(2,:); psd_data_pre(3,:)-psd_data_pre(4,:)];
        %labels{1} = [days{1} ' stim - baseline'];
        %labels{2} = [days{2} ' stim - baseline'];
        figure;
        hold on;
        for iPlot = 1:size(psd_data, 1)
            plot(freq, 10*log10(psd_data(iPlot, :)),'LineWidth', 2);
        end
        hold off;
        
        
        xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
        ylabel('Power/Frequency (dB/Hz)');
        xlim([0 100]);
        title(['PSD for ' species{iSpecies} ' ' num2str(frequencies(iFreq)) 'Hz']);
        legend(labels, 'Interpreter', 'none');
        
        
        save_path = fullfile(save_dir, [species{iSpecies} '_' num2str(frequencies(iFreq)) 'hz.png']);
        saveas(gcf, save_path);
    end
end


eeglab nogui;


data_dir = '/Users/andrewxue/Documents/MATLAB/mousedata';
save_dir = '/Users/andrewxue/Documents/MATLAB/data/matlabgraphs';
frequencies = [4, 35, 40, 45];
species = {'mouse1', 'mouse2'};
days = {'Day1', 'Day2'};
days2 = {'Alive','Dead'};
baseline_str = 'baseline';


for iDay = 1:length(days)
    day_dir = fullfile(data_dir, days{iDay});
    files = dir(fullfile(day_dir, '*.edf'));
    for iSpecies = 1:length(species)
        psd_data = [];
        psd_data_pre = [];
        labels = {};
        for iFile = 1:length(files)
            filename = files(iFile).name;
            
            if contains(filename, species{iSpecies}) && contains(filename, days2{iDay}) 
                
                disp(1)
                EEG = pop_biosig(fullfile(day_dir, filename));
                EEG = eeg_checkset(EEG);
                
                data1 = EEG.data(1, :);
                data2 = EEG.data(2, :);
                
                window = hamming(1024); 
                noverlap = 512; 
                nfft = 1024; 
                [psd1, freq] = pwelch(data1, window, noverlap, nfft, EEG.srate);
                total_power1 = trapz(freq, psd1);
                [psd2, freq] = pwelch(data2, window, noverlap, nfft, EEG.srate);
                total_power2 = trapz(freq, psd2);

                if total_power1 < total_power2
                    psd = psd1;
                elseif total_power2 < total_power1
                    psd = psd2;
                end

                
                psd_data = [psd_data; psd'];
                pattern = '(?<=_)[^_]*(?=_)';
                matches = regexp(filename, pattern, 'match');
                extracted_string = matches{1};
                labels{end+1} = extracted_string;
            end
        end

        
        %psd_data_pre = psd_data;
        %psd_data = [psd_data_pre(1,:)-psd_data_pre(2,:); psd_data_pre(3,:)-psd_data_pre(4,:)];
        %labels{1} = [days{1} ' stim - baseline'];
        %labels{2} = [days{2} ' stim - baseline'];
        figure;
        hold on;
        for iPlot = 1:size(psd_data, 1)
            plot(freq, 10*log10(psd_data(iPlot, :)),'LineWidth', 2);
        end
        hold off;

        
        xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
         ylabel('Power/Frequency (dB/Hz)');
         xlim([0 100]);
         title(['PSD for ' species{iSpecies} ' ' days{iDay} 'Hz']);
         legend(labels, 'Interpreter', 'none');
 
         
         save_path = fullfile(save_dir, [species{iSpecies} '_' days{iDay} 'hz.png']);
         saveas(gcf, save_path);
     end
 end
 


Here is one of the graphs it generated
enter image description here
On the other hand, here is the code I have in python. It is slightly different in the sense that it allows me to cut certain minutes off but that shouldnt affect the average y-values that significantly.:
import os
import mne
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import welch
import re 

data_dir = '/Users/andrewxue/Documents/MATLAB/mousedata'
save_dir = '/Users/andrewxue/Documents/MATLAB/data/epochs'
frequencies = [4, 35, 40, 45]
species = ['mouse1', 'mouse2']
days = ['Day1', 'Day2']
days2 = ['Alive', 'Dead']
baseline_str = 'baseline'


def compute_psd(data, sfreq, nfft=1024):
    window = np.hamming(nfft)
    noverlap = nfft // 2
    freqs, psd = welch(data, fs=sfreq, window=window, noverlap=noverlap, nfft=nfft, scaling='density')
    return freqs, psd

# Define y-axis limits based on MATLAB graphs
ymin, ymax = -150, -80


start_time = 0  # Start time in seconds
end_time = 120   # End time in seconds

# PSD computation and plotting with time slicing
for iSpecies in range(len(species)):
    for iFreq in range(len(frequencies)):
        psd_data = []
        labels = []

        for iDay in range(len(days)):
            day_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, days[iDay])
            files = [f for f in os.listdir(day_dir) if f.endswith('.edf')]

            for filename in files:
                if species[iSpecies] in filename and (str(frequencies[iFreq]) + 'hz' in filename or baseline_str in filename):
                    file_path = os.path.join(day_dir, filename)
                    raw = mne.io.read_raw_edf(file_path, preload=True)
                    sfreq = raw.info['sfreq']

                    # Slice data based on start and end times
                    raw.crop(tmin=start_time, tmax=end_time)
                    data1 = raw.get_data(picks=0)
                    data2 = raw.get_data(picks=1)

                    freqs, psd1 = compute_psd(data1[0], sfreq)
                    freqs, psd2 = compute_psd(data2[0], sfreq)

                    total_power1 = np.trapz(psd1, freqs)
                    total_power2 = np.trapz(psd2, freqs)

                    psd = psd1 if total_power1 < total_power2 else psd2

                    psd_data.append(psd)
                    if baseline_str in filename:
                        labels.append(f"{days[iDay]} baseline")
                    else:
                        labels.append(f"{days[iDay]} {frequencies[iFreq]}hz")

        plt.figure()
        for iPlot in range(len(psd_data)):
            plt.plot(freqs, 10 * np.log10(psd_data[iPlot]), linewidth=2)

        plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
        plt.ylabel('Power/Frequency (dB/Hz)')
        plt.xlim([0, 100])
        plt.ylim([ymin, ymax])  
        plt.title(f'PSD for {species[iSpecies]} {frequencies[iFreq]}Hz (Time: {start_time}-{end_time} s)')
        plt.legend(labels, loc='upper right')

        save_path = os.path.join(save_dir, f"{species[iSpecies]}_{frequencies[iFreq]}hz_{start_time}_{end_time}.png")
        plt.savefig(save_path)
        plt.close()

# Second part of the code for additional conditions (Alive and Dead)
for iDay in range(len(days)):
    day_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, days[iDay])
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(day_dir) if f.endswith('.edf')]

    for iSpecies in range(len(species)):
        psd_data = []
        labels = []

        for filename in files:
            if species[iSpecies] in filename and days2[iDay] in filename:
                file_path = os.path.join(day_dir, filename)
                raw = mne.io.read_raw_edf(file_path, preload=True)
                sfreq = raw.info['sfreq']

                # Slice data based on start and end times
                raw.crop(tmin=start_time, tmax=end_time)
                data1 = raw.get_data(picks=0)
                data2 = raw.get_data(picks=1)

                freqs, psd1 = compute_psd(data1[0], sfreq)
                freqs, psd2 = compute_psd(data2[0], sfreq)

                total_power1 = np.trapz(psd1, freqs)
                total_power2 = np.trapz(psd2, freqs)

                psd = psd1 if total_power1 < total_power2 else psd2

                psd_data.append(psd)
                pattern = r'(?<=_)[^_]*(?=_)'
                matches = re.findall(pattern, filename)
                extracted_string = matches[0]
                labels.append(extracted_string)

        plt.figure()
        for iPlot in range(len(psd_data)):
            plt.plot(freqs, 10 * np.log10(psd_data[iPlot]), linewidth=2)

        plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
        plt.ylabel('Power/Frequency (dB/Hz)')
        plt.xlim([0, 100])
        plt.ylim([ymin, ymax])  
        plt.title(f'PSD for {species[iSpecies]} {days[iDay]}Hz (Time: {start_time}-{end_time} s)')
        plt.legend(labels, loc='upper right')

        save_path = os.path.join(save_dir, f"{species[iSpecies]}_{days[iDay]}hz_{start_time}_{end_time}.png")
        plt.savefig(save_path)
        plt.close()

Here two graphs that this code generated. One is the full duration that includes messy data and one cuts out the first two minutes and results in cleaner data. As you can see in both graphs, the y-axis values differ from the matlab graph y-axis values.
Dirty data
Clean data
Am I graphing the y-axis differently than my peer or what am I doing differently?
